# Converting character to Date

Tags: r, date

I have a vector with dates in the following format:

```
 dates <- c("01AUG2006","01DEC2006","01JUN2006","01MAY2007")
```

To convert this vector to an object of class `Date`, I wrote this function:

```
convert2Date <- function(x) {
  require(car)
  d <- substr(x,0,2)
  m.text <- substr(x,3,5)
  m <- Recode(m.text, "'JAN'=1 ;'FEB'=2;'MAR'=3;'APR'=4;'MAY'=5;'JUN'=6; 
                       'JUL'=7;'AUG'=8;'SEP'=9;'OCT'=10;'NOV'=11;'DEC'=12")
  y <- substr(x,6,9)
  out <- as.Date(paste(d,m,y,sep="/"),"%d/%m/%Y")
  out
}
```

Using the example `dates` variable:

```
test <- convert2Date(dates)
[1] "2006-08-01" "2006-12-01" "2006-06-01" "2007-05-01"
class(test)
[1] "Date"
```

This works, but it looks somewhat cumbersome and only works for this specific format. Since this is probably a common problem, there must be an simpler and more versatile way of doing this. Any suggestions anyone? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your locale. Just like mine.

My system is Portuguese

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                         LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252
```

If I simply try

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(c("01AUG2006","01DEC2006","01JUN2006","01MAY2007"))
[1] NA               NA               "2006-06-01 UTC" NA              
Warning message:
 3 failed to parse.
```

Without locale resetting, `lubridate::dmy` will work for me if I change Months to the Portuguese abrev form.

```
dmy(c("01AGO2006","01DEZ2006","01JUN2006","01MAI2007"))
[1] "2006-08-01 UTC" "2006-12-01 UTC" "2006-06-01 UTC" "2007-05-01 UTC"
```

OR set locale from dmy function call, which turn out to be pretty easier.

```
dmy(dates, locale = "English_United States.1252") # Without resetting locale
[1] "2006-08-01 UTC" "2006-12-01 UTC" "2006-06-01 UTC" "2007-05-01 UTC"
```

It is OK now.

for non-English systems, locale must be changed accordingly or text rewritten.

Resetting locale to US English 2252

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
dates <- c("01AUG2006","01DEC2006","01JUN2006","01MAY2007")
dmy(dates)
[1] "2006-08-01 UTC" "2006-12-01 UTC" "2006-06-01 UTC" "2007-05-01 UTC"
```

The same works now for `Date` after resetting locale

```
as.Date(dates,format="%d%b%Y")
# [1] "2006-08-01" "2006-12-01" "2006-06-01" "2007-05-01"
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Is there a specific reason why the "English_United States.1252" locale does work and my default locale "Dutch_Netherlands.1252" doesn't?

Comment: @Rob, The issue is how abbreviated months are spelled in different locales. See e.g. my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985477/date-conversion-without-specifying-the-format/22986495#22986495)

Comment: @Rob You are providing English abrev. names for Months. Change it to dutch ones to avoid change locale.

Comment: For completeness, I would suggest adding a couple of lines to this to save the old locale and restoring it after you're done converting dates (or use @G.Grothendieck's answer)

Answer (score 7):

It looks as though

```
as.Date(dates,format="%d%b%Y")
```

works fine?

```
[1] "2006-08-01" "2006-12-01" "2006-06-01" "2007-05-01"
```

Comment: It doesn't work here, but surely because my locale is not english.

Comment: you can probably convert your locale temporarily -- this is something I've done before but forget how at the moment, see `?Sys.getlocale` ...

Answer (score 2):

This is also involves parsing out the substrings but its shorter and does not require setting the locale:

```
as.Date(paste(substr(dates, 6, 9), # year
              match(substr(dates, 3, 5), toupper(month.abb)), # month
              substr(dates, 1, 2), # day
              sep = "-"))
```

Comment: this is nice.  It's a bit trickier if you have to go in the other direction (i.e. handle non-English abbreviations from an English-speaking locale) -- then the locale-setting approach might win for generality

Comment: @G. Grothendieck I like the match part and the constants. New for me! Thanks!