# How can I parse date in another language?

Tags: r

My local environment is French :

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

I would like to parse date in English but I don't know how to enter this parameter to my function.

If the date is in French, everything works :

```
> as.Date("15 mai 2004", "%d %B %Y")
[1] "2004-05-15"
```

If I have a date in English, it doesn't work :

```
> as.Date("15 mai 2004", "%d %B %Y")
[1] "2004-05-15"
```

> as.Date("15 may 2004", "%d %B %Y")
>   [1] NA

Comment: I don't think there is a way other than changing your locale (see `help("locales")`).

Comment: You can use `Sys.setlocale()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting character to Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218555/converting-character-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution :

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "en_GB.UTF-8")
as.Date("15 may 2004", "%d %B %Y")
```